# How to measure energy consumption of a process in linux without any external hardware meter?

Tags: linux, process, intel, energy, msr

I had tried googling for it and had found **MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS** under [**RAPL**](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/docs/d3/df9/linux-rapl_8c_source.html) but unfortunately it has support for only newer processors like Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge etc. Is there any other way to get it in older processors?

This is my processor : http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz

I am not looking for a method just for this specific one but trying to find all the possible options for the models older than Sandy Bridge.

Comment: Probably more for your computer than writing this comment

Comment: You probably should measure the power consumption of the entire computer (including motherboard, disks, and perhaps screen) with an external hardware meter.

Comment: @EdHeal Added the details.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Using external hardware is not an option. I want to look at software options only. Forgot to mention it in the question. My bad. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Install `powertop` then run `powertop` with root permission.

In ubuntu:

*Install*: `sudo apt-get install powertop`

*Run*: `sudo powertop`